# ¿Es posible filtrar un MongoDB sobre el valor de una field cuyo valor es una lista de diccionarios?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, diccionarios, pymongo

Quiero saber si es posible obtener todos los documentos de una base de datos MongoDB consultando sobre los elementos de un campo cuyo valor es una lista. Por ejemplo aquí `q2.Results` tiene una lista de comentarios y me gustaría obtener todos los documentos donde el `UserNickname` de la persona que escribió el comentario es `Jackobear` :

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fd5e617260828c7646000aa"
  },
  "q2": {
    "Id": "q2",
    "Locale": "fr_FR",
    "Results": [
      {
        "Id": "163069310",
        "CID": "eb523c23-980d-5661-b9d0-c6dc1028fa42",
        "SourceClient": "sephora-fr",
        "Badges": {
          "loyaltyYes--Im-a-VIB-Rouge": {
            "ContentType": "REVIEW",
            "Id": "loyaltyYes--Im-a-VIB-Rouge",
            "BadgeType": "Custom"
          }
        },
        "BadgesOrder": [
          "loyaltyYes--Im-a-VIB-Rouge"
        ],
        "LastModeratedTime": "2020-09-22T12:00:18.000+00:00",
        "LastModificationTime": "2020-12-10T14:36:16.000+00:00",
        "ProductId": "P3742199",
        "CampaignId": "BV_PIE_ONLINE",
        "ContextDataValuesOrder": [
          "Gender",
          "Eyes",
          "Skin"
        ],
        "UserLocation": "Paris",
        "AuthorId": "78948942",
        "ContentLocale": "fr_FR",
        "IsFeatured": false,
        "TotalInappropriateFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "0"
        },
        "TotalClientResponseCount": {
          "$numberInt": "0"
        },
        "TotalCommentCount": {
          "$numberInt": "0"
        },
        "Rating": {
          "$numberInt": "5"
        },
        "IsRatingsOnly": false,
        "IsRecommended": true,
        "Helpfulness": {
          "$numberDouble": "1.0"
        },
        "TotalFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "2"
        },
        "TotalNegativeFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "0"
        },
        "TotalPositiveFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "2"
        },
        "ModerationStatus": "APPROVED",
        "SubmissionId": "r23232-fr__16007743UA3Zr3O9L5",
        "SubmissionTime": "2020-09-22T11:32:57.000+00:00",
        "ReviewText": "J’adore, il sent le bord de mer une ressemblance avec le parfum Kenzo",
        "Title": "Très bon parfum",
        "UserNickname": "Jackobear",
        "ContextDataValues": {
          "Gender": {
            "Value": "Male",
            "Id": "Gender"
          },
          "Skin": {
            "Value": "Normale",
            "Id": "Skin"
          },
          "Eyes": {
            "Value": "Marrons",
            "Id": "Eyes"
          }
        },
        "Videos": [],
        "Pros": null,
        "InappropriateFeedbackList": [],
        "SecondaryRatings": {},
        "ClientResponses": [],
        "Photos": [],
        "Cons": null,
        "IsSyndicated": false,
        "SecondaryRatingsOrder": [],
        "AdditionalFields": {},
        "RatingRange": {
          "$numberInt": "5"
        },
        "TagDimensions": {},
        "AdditionalFieldsOrder": [],
        "ProductRecommendationIds": [],
        "CommentIds": [],
        "TagDimensionsOrder": []
      },
      {
        "Id": "129228166",
        "CID": "66aec0c2-04b0-57d2-aa9f-ac3b7ecb91df",
        "SourceClient": "sephora-fr",
        "Badges": {
          "loyaltyYes--Im-a-beauty-insider": {
            "ContentType": "REVIEW",
            "Id": "loyaltyYes--Im-a-beauty-insider",
            "BadgeType": "Custom"
          }
        },
        "BadgesOrder": [
          "loyaltyYes--Im-a-beauty-insider"
        ],
        "LastModeratedTime": "2019-06-12T00:15:07.000+00:00",
        "LastModificationTime": "2020-02-07T10:11:38.000+00:00",
        "ProductId": "P3742199",
        "CampaignId": "BV_REVIEW_DISPLAY",
        "ContextDataValuesOrder": [
          "Gender",
          "Age",
          "Eyes",
          "Skin"
        ],
        "UserLocation": "Bayeux",
        "AuthorId": "78051240",
        "ContentLocale": "fr_FR",
        "IsFeatured": false,
        "InappropriateFeedbackList": [
          {
            "AuthorId": "ztn5x2jvnf5u8llq2jagt7j4mp",
            "SubmissionTime": "2019-06-11T23:12:44.000+00:00"
          },
          {
            "AuthorId": "zpebdw7hh48w5zpr3778nx2hgg",
            "SubmissionTime": "2019-06-06T23:20:57.000+00:00"
          },
          {
            "AuthorId": "zkvy1qeaaz8s2znk6kesfg3dnb",
            "SubmissionTime": "2019-06-03T20:01:34.000+00:00"
          }
        ],
        "TotalInappropriateFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "3"
        },
        "TotalClientResponseCount": {
          "$numberInt": "0"
        },
        "TotalCommentCount": {
          "$numberInt": "0"
        },
        "Rating": {
          "$numberInt": "5"
        },
        "IsRatingsOnly": false,
        "IsRecommended": true,
        "Helpfulness": {
          "$numberDouble": "0.8999999761581421"
        },
        "TotalFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "40"
        },
        "TotalNegativeFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "4"
        },
        "TotalPositiveFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "36"
        },
        "ModerationStatus": "APPROVED",
        "SubmissionId": "halilss25hcanccb0yj6nxvpk",
        "SubmissionTime": "2019-06-03T11:43:04.000+00:00",
        "ReviewText": "Un parfum enivrant mais pas entêtant, la note de tête est exquise et très fraîche, parfaite pour l'été. Vous devriez vendre ce parfum dans plus de sephora et avec plus de stock!!",
        "Title": "Parfait pour l'été",
        "UserNickname": "Abraxas",
        "ContextDataValues": {
          "Age": {
            "Value": "18to24",
            "Id": "Age"
          },
          "Gender": {
            "Value": "Female",
            "Id": "Gender"
          },
          "Skin": {
            "Value": "Grasse",
            "Id": "Skin"
          },
          "Eyes": {
            "Value": "Bleus",
            "Id": "Eyes"
          }
        },
        "Videos": [],
        "Pros": null,
        "SecondaryRatings": {},
        "ClientResponses": [],
        "Photos": [],
        "Cons": null,
        "IsSyndicated": false,
        "SecondaryRatingsOrder": [],
        "AdditionalFields": {},
        "RatingRange": {
          "$numberInt": "5"
        },
        "TagDimensions": {},
        "AdditionalFieldsOrder": [],
        "ProductRecommendationIds": [],
        "CommentIds": [],
        "TagDimensionsOrder": []
      }
    ],
    "HasErrors": false,
    "Errors": []
  },
  "name": "L'Atelier des Subtils Eau d'Océan - Eau de toilette",
}
```

Pensaba a una causa como hacer un `find_all` con:

```
users = ['Jackobear']
collection.findall({'q2.Results.x.UserNickname' : {'$in': users}})
```

Si no es posible, ¿Supongo que tengo que hacer una nueva base de datos con los perfumes apreciados por cada persona? ¿Cómo puedo hacer el script que podría recuperar esta información de la base de datos buscando estos documentos para cada usuario?

Intenté con la respuesta de Daniel:

```
def collaborative_recommendation(users, k):
    # je veux tous les items que l'utilisateur a liké
    list(collection.aggregate([
        { $project:{
            "q2.Results":{ $filter:{
                input: "q2.Results",
                as:"resultado",
                cond: {$eq: ["$$resultado.UserNickname", users]}
            }}
        }}
    ]))
    # et on fait une recommendation par user
    return None
```

Ademas utiliso Python, pero parece que Python hay problemas para entender esto. En efecto obtengo:

```
OperationFailure at /recommend/
input to $filter must be an array not string, full error: {'operationTime': Timestamp(1620134892, 3), 'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'input to $filter must be an array not string', 'code': 28651, 'codeName': 'Location28651', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1620134892, 3), 'signature': {'hash': b'?\xf6\xff\xfe\x16G*<rzD\xc2B\xa5d\xf1\xfb\xea2U', 'keyId': 6914681777856446469}}}
```

Comment: No te funciona con `q2.Results.UserNickname` ???

Comment: Todo el contenido es un solo documento, entonces si te entiendo bien quieres el mismo documento pero solo con los sub documentos donde `q2.Results.UserNickname` es igual a `Jackobear`, verdad?

Comment: Por favor si la respuesta te fue útil marca como aceptado.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución a este problema se puede resolver con `aggregate` de **mongodb** y nos ayudamos con `$filtet` para que la solución sea mas eficiente.

```
db.Prueba.aggregate([
{ $match: { "_id": ObjectId("5fd5e617260828c7646000aa") } },
{ $project: {
        "q2.Results": { $filter: { 
                input: "$q2.Results",
                as: "resultado",
                cond: { $eq: [ "$$resultado.UserNickname", "Jackobear" ] }
           }
        }
    } 
}
])
```

Entonces el resultado muestra el documento completo pero con los sub documentos de la matriz (Array) **q2.Results** cuyo valor de **UserNickname** es igual a **"Jackobear"**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd5e617260828c7646000aa"),
    "q2" : {
        "Results" : [ 
            {
                "Id" : "163069310",
                "CID" : "eb523c23-980d-5661-b9d0-c6dc1028fa42",
                "SourceClient" : "sephora-fr",
                "Badges" : {
                    "loyaltyYes--Im-a-VIB-Rouge" : {
                        "ContentType" : "REVIEW",
                        "Id" : "loyaltyYes--Im-a-VIB-Rouge",
                        "BadgeType" : "Custom"
                    }
                },
                "BadgesOrder" : [ 
                    "loyaltyYes--Im-a-VIB-Rouge"
                ],
                "LastModeratedTime" : "2020-09-22T12:00:18.000+00:00",
                "LastModificationTime" : "2020-12-10T14:36:16.000+00:00",
                "ProductId" : "P3742199",
                "CampaignId" : "BV_PIE_ONLINE",
                "ContextDataValuesOrder" : [ 
                    "Gender", 
                    "Eyes", 
                    "Skin"
                ],
                "UserLocation" : "Paris",
                "AuthorId" : "78948942",
                "ContentLocale" : "fr_FR",
                "IsFeatured" : false,
                "TotalInappropriateFeedbackCount" : {
                    "$numberInt" : "0"
                },
                "TotalClientResponseCount" : {
                    "$numberInt" : "0"
                },
                "TotalCommentCount" : {
                    "$numberInt" : "0"
                },
                "Rating" : {
                    "$numberInt" : "5"
                },
                "IsRatingsOnly" : false,
                "IsRecommended" : true,
                "Helpfulness" : {
                    "$numberDouble" : "1.0"
                },
                "TotalFeedbackCount" : {
                    "$numberInt" : "2"
                },
                "TotalNegativeFeedbackCount" : {
                    "$numberInt" : "0"
                },
                "TotalPositiveFeedbackCount" : {
                    "$numberInt" : "2"
                },
                "ModerationStatus" : "APPROVED",
                "SubmissionId" : "r23232-fr__16007743UA3Zr3O9L5",
                "SubmissionTime" : "2020-09-22T11:32:57.000+00:00",
                "ReviewText" : "J’adore, il sent le bord de mer une ressemblance avec le parfum Kenzo",
                "Title" : "Très bon parfum",
                "UserNickname" : "Jackobear",
                "ContextDataValues" : {
                    "Gender" : {
                        "Value" : "Male",
                        "Id" : "Gender"
                    },
                    "Skin" : {
                        "Value" : "Normale",
                        "Id" : "Skin"
                    },
                    "Eyes" : {
                        "Value" : "Marrons",
                        "Id" : "Eyes"
                    }
                },
                "Videos" : [],
                "Pros" : null,
                "InappropriateFeedbackList" : [],
                "SecondaryRatings" : {},
                "ClientResponses" : [],
                "Photos" : [],
                "Cons" : null,
                "IsSyndicated" : false,
                "SecondaryRatingsOrder" : [],
                "AdditionalFields" : {},
                "RatingRange" : {
                    "$numberInt" : "5"
                },
                "TagDimensions" : {},
                "AdditionalFieldsOrder" : [],
                "ProductRecommendationIds" : [],
                "CommentIds" : [],
                "TagDimensionsOrder" : []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Daniel! Sin embargo como hacer si hay mucho mas elementos que solo el con `ObjectId("5fd5e617260828c7646000aa")`.